# Join/Merge text files (with ID) in Python

Tags: python, merge

I am quite new in python programming.

I can merge tables but now I am in trouble when I have to merge/join tables with specific IDs.

I have two .txt files !

In txt1  I have numbers (IDs) like:

```
5
3
4
1
2
```

In txt2 I have coordinates with IDs

```
1 733786 102807
2 734475 102995
3 735009 103403
4 734878 103728
5 735694 103722
```

I would like to get a result something like that (or similar) where I can see the right coordinates next to the numbers in txt1 with keeping the order

```
5 735694 103722
3 735009 103403
4 734878 103728
1 733786 102807
2 734475 102995
```

I have tried to use this code

```
with open("1.txt", "r") as a, open("2.txt", "r") as b:
    h = {line1.strip():line2.strip() for line1,line2 in zip(a,b)}
with open("RESULT.txt", "w") as out:
    for k,v in h.iteritems():
        out.write("{} {}\n".format(k,v))
```

but it gives the following result where the joins are good but the order is not and it would be important

```
1 4 734878 103728
3 2 734475 102995
2 5 735694 103722
5 1 733786 102807
4 3 735009 103403
```

Comment: have you actually tried something you want to show us to help you with? or are you just hoping that someone will do your work or homework for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("text2") as f:
     data = dict(row.split(None,1) for row in f)
with open("output.txt","wb") as f_out,open("text1") as f:
     for line in f:
         f_out.write("%s %s" % (line.strip,data.get(line.strip(),""))
```

Comment: Thank you very much to you as well !

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Welcome to SO. Next time please show us what you tried so far, so that we can help you better.

```
with open('txt1.txt') as file1:
    txt1 = file1.read().splitlines()

with open('txt2.txt') as file2:
    txt2 = file2.read().splitlines()

with open('txt1.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    new = ''
    for line_a in txt1:
        for line_b in txt2:
            if line_a[0] == line_b[0]:
                new_file.write(line_b + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I would do but I was afraid my version is a dead end !